# Set Environment variable in CMake in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to get my head around some JNI/NDK stuff and  have some C code to compile and libraries to link to. However the C code includes a file that expects certain Environment Variables to be set.

I have a *.inc file with these variables defined which can be used in an Android.mk file when building with ndk-build.

My Question is, when using Android Studio, and therefore gradle and CMake, how can I pass environment variables to the C code, preferably by somehow 'including' the .inc file I have, though it is understandable to replace this particular file is formatting of variables is not correct.

To simplify the question I am trying to use Googles examples for use in Android Studio. So I am using the hello-libs example (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs).

If I add the following snippet of code to hello-libs.cpp it will fail to build unless I set that variable:

```
#ifndef TEST
#error "TEST NOT DEFINED"
#endif
```

How do I export/set TEST?

Comment: are you sure you're talking about environment variables, and not preprocessor defines?